# Firebase ui auth dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I found two firebase ui auth dependencies definitions in documentation and sample code used for build.gradle. What is difference between them and which one I should use?

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0")
```

And:

```
implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0")
```

Comment: Can you please indicate where did you find those dependencies? The URLs of the resources will be fine.

Comment: my fault. ` com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth` is right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the dependencies that are present in [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) with the ones that exist in the [Firebase-UI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). So the following dependency:

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0")
```

Is present inside the Firebase-UI library, while:

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1")
```

Is present inside [Firebase Android SDK Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android). Please note that the version is `22.3.1` and not `7.2.0` and there is **no** `-ui` present.